# Ignoring '#', on page refresh not working Backbone Routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I am facing a problem in routing my pages using backbone.

1. I have replaced `#` with `/` by using `pushState : true` and `root:giving the actual parent root`
2. When I am clicking on the link then for the first time, it is properly navigating. Used `Backbone.history.navigate('xyz',true)`.
3. But when I do a page reload with / then the page is going to 404 error, file not found.
4. Is there a way to stop appending index.html to the URL.
5. I need URL like : `localhost:8080/abc/login?sid=123`, instead of this `localhost:8080/abc/index.html#login?sid=123`

Router:

```
define([ 'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone' ], function($, _, Backbone) {

    var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
        lView: function (route, name, path) {
            var self = this;
            self.route(route, name, function () {
                require([path], function (module) {
                    var view = new module(name);
                    view.render();
                });
            });
        }
    });

    var App = {
        ROOT: "/abc/",
        router : new AppRouter()
    };

    var initialize = function(){
        var app_router = new AppRouter();
        app_router.lView('*actions', 'login', 'loginView');
        Backbone.history.start({
            root: App.ROOT,
            pushState: true
        });
    };
    return {
        initialize: initialize
    };
});
```

Comment: why don't you define your routes inside the Backbone Router using **routes** ? like `{routes: {"login/:sid": "login"}, login: function(sid){do something with sid}}`

Comment: I am facing the same issue did you find a fix?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38320519/backbone-route-with-push-state-not-working-on-page-refresh