# Backbone route with push state not working on page refresh

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router, pushstate

```
var Backbone = require('backbone'),
SellerProfileView = require('./views/seller/SellerProfileView');

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        ":user_name" : "sellerProfile"
    },
    sellerProfile: function (username) {
        "use strict";
        var sellerProfile = new SellerProfileView({username: username});
    }
});

module.exports = Router


var Router = require('./router'),
    Backbone = require('backbone'),
    $ = require('jquery');

var app = {
    init: function () {
        "use strict";
        Backbone.$ = $;
        this.router = new Router();
        $(document).ready(function () {
            Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true, route: '/' });
        });
    }
};

module.exports = app;
app.init();
```

I get the below error if i refresh the page without the hash

**Error response**

Error code 404.

Message: File not found.

Error code explanation: 404 = Nothing matches the given URI.

Please help.

Comment: Did you try setting up a default root route? Like `"" : "index"`?

Comment: Yes.. doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

pushState will try to load the ressource.And it seems your server is not loading anything at 'yourwebsiteurl.com/'

Comment: Will it work if i redirect my server to the index.html right now i am running a normal http-server